# Azure Data factory: How to read username and password in C# from Http Connector

Tags: c#, rest, azure-data-factory, basic-authentication

I am using Azure Data factory HTTP connector as a linked service to read data from the REST endpoint using basic authentication.
`{
    "name": "LS_HTTP",
    "properties": {
        "hubName": "Hub name",
        "type": "Http",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "http://*****.azurewebsites.net",
            "authenticationType": "Basic",
            "gatewayName": "",
            "encryptedCredential": "",
            "username": "test",
            "password": "**********",
            "enableServerCertificateValidation": true
        }
    }
}`

Following code snippet is written to fetch the username and password from the headerin my web API

```
string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
{
    //Extract credentials   
    string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();  
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));    
    int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');
    var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
    var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);  

    if (username == "test" && password == "****")
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    // no authorization header
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
    return;
}
```

When I run Azure data factory pipeline with this setup, I am not able to get username and password from the request header in the web api, basically Authorization header itself is null. 
Help me to fetch the username and password passed from my ADF connector service in my web API.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your definition, you're working with Data Factory v1. I see you configure some properties that are not required for basic authentication.

encryptedCredential, is not required. [The documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-http-connector#linked-service-properties):

> Description: Encrypted credential to access the HTTP endpoint. Auto-generated when you configure the authentication information in copy wizard or the ClickOnce popup dialog.
>
> Required: No. Apply only when copying data from an on-premises HTTP server.

gatewayName, is not required since you're not using an on-premises HTTP server

> Description: Name of the Data Management Gateway to connect to an on-premises HTTP source.

enableServerCertificateValidation, already defaults to true

Documentation gives this basic example:

```
{
"name": "HttpLinkedService",
"properties":
{
    "type": "Http",
    "typeProperties":
    {
        "authenticationType": "basic",
        "url" : "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/",
        "userName": "user name",
        "password": "password"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I had tried with above configurations as well, but it is not working